# D3200 "Lighting is Poor; Flash Recommended" with 35mm f1.8DX lens on Manual

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, nikon-d3200

Yesterday I took my D3200 out with a 35mm f1.8 and 70-300 f4-5.6 lens for some fall shots at a park. I pulled my camera out of the bag, mounted the 35, switched to manual, lined up my shot, and then...

...nothing. It wouldn't take a picture. The camera complained about poor lighting, even though it was a bright, sunny day. The camera AF'd fine and the metering in the viewfinder was fine as well. It just refused to take a picture. I pointed it down at the ground and it fired a few times. There was no flash mounted.

Frustrated, because the camera was set to manual and should therefore not care about the lighting, I tried the 70-300 which worked perfectly. I swapped back to the 35 and it worked for a few shots before stopping again with the same error. Reseating the lens seemed to get one or two shots out of it.

I spent the afternoon with the 70-300, switching back to the 35mm towards the evening which now worked fine. There was nothing wrong with the shots in post.

I inspected the lens and there was no visible damage to the glass or aperture mechanism. The only cause I can think of was that it was unusually cold, but still above freezing.

What's the cause of this problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Try cleaning the contacts (the interface between the lens and the camera).

Comment: I didn't find this message in the manual. It is showed on a main LCD?

Answer (score 1):

If it's doing it with the 35mm lens and not with the 70-300mm, then it's most likely a problem with the 35mm. Try cleaning the contacts on the camera and the lens, and check that they haven't been damaged or overly scratched.

The contacts are only attached to the lens mount by a small chip, so it could be that something on the lens mount or in the lens body has come loose.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem with the new Nikon Z50 and I found a solution. Menu - custom settings - autofocus - AF-C priority selection has to be set to release and not focus. Then it stopped giving me that message.